# How to check that new instantiation of class is proper data type (python)

Tags: python, oop, class

I want to create a class that accepts data only in a specific format, and otherwise returns an error.  For example,

```
class Sentence:
  def __init__(self, input):
    self.initial_input = input

## Check and assign input
if  isinstance(input, (list, tuple)):
  self.tagged = input
else: raise TypeError, ('Input must be a list.')
```

This code seems to get the job done, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to do this, perhaps by using some built-in feature of classes in python.  I have a lot of arguments that need to be in specific formats, so my `def __init__` is getting pretty unwieldy when set up like this.  Is there any reason not to handle checking the initial instantiation of a new class object this way?  I've tried looking around quite a bit, but can't find much.

Comment: Actually, we don't waste time on this kind of thing.  Think for a second.  What does "wrong data format" mean?   It means something will crash. If you get a non-list, it will --eventually-- crash. So... When it crashes, find and fix the problem.  It's Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than to Ask for Permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is common in Python, so checking the type is usually discouraged unless absolutely necessary. Generally, if an argument must be of some specific type, it is best to assume that the user has provided the correct type. This allows the user to provide something that isn't quite right but still works, and it allows you to use mock objects for testing purposes. In some cases, it might be useful to just try to convert whatever the user has given you into what you want. In your example case, you might just do: `self.tagged = list(input)`. The `list` constructor will accept a wide variety of sequences (which the user might want to use, but might not be sufficient for your needs) and makes a list out of it.

Sometimes, though, you do need *some* kind of check. E.g., if the function is supposed to accept lists or dicts and do something different depending on which you provided. In these situations, you can use Python's abstract base class system. See the classes in the [collections](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes) and [numbers](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html#module-numbers) module. Using these, you could do an `isinstance` check to see if something is a `Sequence`, `Mapping`, or `Number` without explicitly naming all the possibilities. You may have noticed that the `list`, `dict`, and `int` classes do not actually derive from `Sequence`, `Mapping`, and `Number`, but that's ok - abstract classes get to determine what classes count as subclasses for the purposes of the `isinstance` function. You can use the [abc](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#module-abc) module to define new abstract classes of this sort. So if you have to do a lot of checks for a specific set of classes, you might find it easier and cleaner to define an abstract class that claims them as its own. Then, later, you can add more classes (or programmatic checking) to the abstract class to cover more cases without needing to update all the places where you needed to make the check.